# Check if list contains only and all numbers from 1 to 9, with no duplicates

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

If I have a list:

```
[6, 7, 4, 8, 9, 5, 3, 2, 1]
```

I want to make sure that every number from 1 to 9 is in the list, with no repeats, and no other numbers. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: `sorted(my_list) == list(range(1, 10))`

Comment: @Selcuk: *"from 1 to 9 is in the list, with no repeats, and no other numbers."* As per it, there is the possibility of missing numbers (as not mentioned in question). In that case it will fail.

Comment: @anonymous Did you notice the solution that Selcuk posted in the comment right before yours?

Comment: @anonymous Note the words _every number_.

Comment: @Selcuk: I missed *every*. You are right!

Comment: @Selcuk I posted your answer as a community answer. If you want to put it as your own I can remove it.

Comment: @idjaw Nope, that's fine. Thanks for taking time to post it as an answer.

Comment: @Selcuk It works well for me, thanks

Comment: @Vermillion In the future, please make sure you familiarize yourself with [how to ask an on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question, and how to put together a [mcve]. Typically questions like this should not be answered as there was no code attempt made by the question asker and should be closed as too-broad until relevant code and problem is specified.

Comment: @idjaw Just for clarification, what is this question missing? I have posted working example code in past questions, and was told to go to code review

Comment: @Vermillion If you were told to go to code review that was incorrect. Sorry that happened. If you did post fully functional code it is understandable that you would be told to go there but the SO community needs to get out of the habit of doing that. What your question is missing right now is your latest code attempt and the problems you were facing in your implementation.

Comment: @idjaw Thanks for the help, I'll do that in future questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good way to solve this type of problem:

By sorting the list, and comparing equality against a list ranging from 1 - 9, you will cover all cases per the requirement of all numbers 1 to 9 with no duplicates:

```
sorted(my_list) == list(range(1, 10))
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> sorted(my_list) == list(range(1, 10))
True

>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,9]
>>> sorted(my_list) == list(range(1, 10))
False

>>> my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> sorted(my_list) == list(range(1, 10))
False
```